# HTML 5 Canvas zooming rendering is very slow

Tags: html, html5-canvas, zooming

I am using HTML 5 canvas for drawing image and drawing annotations on that using paper.js.

I am trying to implement zooming functionality for Canvas. For this I am using scale function for that. As user try to do zoom then first i scale the canvas and then redraw the content.

But suppose if, there is much content on the Canvas, then it make slow to the process. It takes some while to render.

What can I do for this ?? Please suggest me feasible solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with WEBGL rendering , WebGL is hardware accelerated so smoother operations than canvas. Three.js library provides webGL rendering option , latest browser version supports it.